# How to Ignore a Whole Line of Text that Starts with // Using a Scanner Class and Delimiters

Tags: java

I am trying to read data from a `.txt` file, i need to be ignoring any line that starts with a `//` or a blank line but i can't seem to get the delimiter to work correctly.

```
public void readVehicleData()
throws FileNotFoundException
{
    FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(myFrame, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileBox.setVisible(true);

    String filename = fileBox.getFile();
    File vehicleData = new File(filename);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(vehicleData).useDelimiter("\"(,\")?");


    while( scanner.hasNext() )
    {
        String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(lineOfText);

    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

This is the .txt file i am trying to read:

```
// this is a comment, any lines that start with //
// (and blank lines) should be ignored

AA, TF-63403, MJ09TFE, Fiat 
A, TF-61273, MJ09TFD, Fiat
A, TF-64810, NR59GHD, Ford
B , TF-68670,MA59DCS, Vauxhall
B, TF-61854,  MJ09TFG, Fiat
B, TF-69215, PT09TAW, Peugeot
C, TF-67358, NR59GHM, Ford
```

Comment: Read a line at a time with `BufferedReader` or any type of `Reader` and just ignore lines that fulfill those conditions.

Comment: Use a BufferedReader to read line by line. For each line, test if it's blank or if it starts with "//". The javadoc of BufferedReader and of String are your friends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

Comment: If I answered your question, please accept it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question properly, you do not need to specify a delimiter.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(vehicleData);


while( scanner.hasNext() )
{
    String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();
    if(lineOfText.length() == 0 || lineOfText.startsWith("//"))
            continue;
    System.out.println(lineOfText);

}
scanner.close();
```

Comment: Effective where you have to read file line by line.... Any solution for the case where required record spans multiple lines whereas the comments to be ignored can only be one-liners...?